# inputAccessoryView dismisses, but keyboard won't?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a `UITextView` with an `inputAccessoryView` that contains a `toolbar` with a "Done" button so that the user can end the editing process. Inside the method fired by pressing the Done button, I call `resignFirstResponder` on the `UITextView` to dismiss the keyboard.

So when I tap "Done", the accessory view disappears, but the keyboard itself remains.  I am completely stumped as to why this might be happening, or where to start looking.  This app is running on iPad with iOS 5.1

Any ideas?

Thanks!  //Scott

Comment: first responder resign to another textview/textfield? thats why keyboard still appearing..

Comment: What if you were to call `endEditing` on the text view's super view instead of the `resignFirstResponder`?  Any change?

Comment: Thant, you were real close. Thanks for making me think. The previous first responder was actually still active, but the keyboard had been deliberately hidden because of the nature of what the app does.  When the UITextView was became first responder, the keyboard became visible again to serve the UITextView, and when it resigned first responder status, the keyboard remained visible for the previous responder.